# Custom ExceptionHandler in Angular 2

Tags: angular, exceptionhandler

I´m trying to implement a central ExceptionHandler in Angular 2. I searched in SO and found several topics about this subject, like those bellow:

[Module '"angular2/angular2"' has no exported member 'ExceptionHandler'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980405/module-angular2-angular2-has-no-exported-member-exceptionhandler)

[How to properly overwrite the exceptionHandler in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489058/how-to-properly-overwrite-the-exceptionhandler-in-angularjs)

But, this topics seem to be outdated.

I´m using Angular 2 RC5, and following the documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ExceptionHandler-class.html), I tried to implement:

```
import { ExceptionHandler } from '@angular/core';
export class CustomExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {

call(error:any, stackTrace:any = null, reason:string = null) {
    // do something with the exception
}
```

}

But I received a error like that *"TS2420 - CustomExceptionHandler incorrectly implements interface ExceptionHandler. Property '_logger' is missing in type 'CustomExceptionHandler'.*

I´am a newbie in TS, but I have been programming in Java for 10 years.

Actually, when I click on ExceptionHandler in IDE (IntelliJ), the code follow up to a class, not a interface.

```
export declare class ExceptionHandler {
    private _logger;
    private _rethrowException;
    constructor(_logger: any, _rethrowException?: boolean);
    static exceptionToString(exception: any, stackTrace?: any, reason?: string): string;
    call(exception: any, stackTrace?: any, reason?: string): void;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3138-creating-a-custom-errorhandler-in-angular-2-rc-6.htm. It seems there have been breaking changes to error handling with RC6, so you might wanna think about updating.

Comment: @etc: where you able to resolve this? did you try the below solution?

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Below is for RC6,

Exceptions is [deprecated for public use see changelog for RC6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md),

> core: Exceptions are no longer part of the public API. We don't expect that anyone should be referring to the Exception types.

```
ExceptionHandler.call(exception: any, stackTrace?: any, reason?: string): void;
```

change to:

```
ErrorHandler.handleError(error: any): void;
```

For implementation using `ErrorHandler`, [see this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html)

```
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}]
})
class MyModule {}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you guys. Works for me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but looks like this information is obsolete, actual documentation could be found on the official site https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler